# spark in running but yarn can't find it

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a problem about yarn cluster
I run hdfs-namenode, hdfs-datanode, yarn at localhost and then run a spark-master and a spark-worker at localhost too, see like this:

```
$ jps  
5809 Main  
53730 ResourceManager  
53540 SecondaryNameNode  
53125 NameNode  
56710 Master  
54009 NodeManager  
56809 Worker  
53308 DataNode  
56911 Jps
```

I can see spark-worker is link to spark-master throw `http://127.0.0.1:8080`
img : spark-web-ui

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

But in yarn web-ui `http://127.0.0.1:8088`, there is nothing in `Nodes of the cluster` page
img :

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

My `conf/spark-env.sh` is

```
export SCALA_HOME="/opt/scala-2.11.8/"  
export JAVA_HOME="/opt/jdk1.8.0_101/"  
export HADOOP_HOME="/opt/hadoop-2.7.3/"  
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="/opt/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop/"  
export SPARK_MASTER_IP=127.0.0.1  
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS="/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/"  
export SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=1G
```

And `conf/spark-defaults.conf` is

```
spark.master                            spark://127.0.0.1:7077  
spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion     false  
spark.yarn.access.namenodes             hdfs://127.0.0.1:8032
```

And `yarn-site.xml` is

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
        <value>127.0.0.1</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8030</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8035</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8033</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
        <value>${yarn.resourcemanager.hostname}:8032</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

When I submit an application use
`spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster test.py`
I can get out put like this

```
16/10/12 16:19:30 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/10/12 16:19:30 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
16/10/12 16:19:30 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
16/10/12 16:19:30 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
16/10/12 16:19:30 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
16/10/12 16:19:30 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
16/10/12 16:19:30 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
16/10/12 16:19:30 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
16/10/12 16:19:31 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
16/10/12 16:19:32 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-3cdb2435-d6a0-4ce0-a54a-f2849d5f4909/__spark_libs__2140674596658903486.zip -> hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1476256306830_0002/__spark_libs__2140674596658903486.zip
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/fuxiuyin/PycharmProjects/spark-test/test.py -> hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1476256306830_0002/test.py
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1476256306830_0002/pyspark.zip
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip -> hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1476256306830_0002/py4j-0.10.1-src.zip
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-3cdb2435-d6a0-4ce0-a54a-f2849d5f4909/__spark_conf__3570291475444079549.zip -> hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000/user/fuxiuyin/.sparkStaging/application_1476256306830_0002/__spark_conf__.zip
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: fuxiuyin
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: fuxiuyin
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to:
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to:
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(fuxiuyin); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(fuxiuyin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1476256306830_0002 to ResourceManager
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1476256306830_0002
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1476256306830_0002 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client:
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1476260373944
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1476256306830_0002/
     user: fuxiuyin
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /opt/spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7/spark-3cdb2435-d6a0-4ce0-a54a-f2849d5f4909
```

It's success, but in yarn web-ui, this app isn't running always in ACCEPTED
[image]

Looks like no spark node run this app.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?
Thanks~

Comment: Use this command to start spark... spark-shell --master yarn-client

Comment: This is nothing to do with spark. There is not enough resource available to run the job. Please check the memory and vcores available in http://127.0.0.1:8088

Comment: @NirmalRam Thanks for your reminder. My problem is solved and I have added an answer to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify one type of cluster:

- YARN (cluster or client mode)
- Spark standalone
- Mesos

You have started Spark standalone server and you're connecting to this cluster manager. If you want to start Spark on YARN, you should specify `yarn` master - just `--master yarn`

Edit:
Please add logs and `spark-submit` command. Please also post how are you launching YARN. If first attempt was wrong, then it means you have configuration problem

Edit number 2: It seems that YARN doesn't have enough resources to process your application. Please check your config, i.e. check if maybe increasing `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` will help. Also you can go to Spark Web UI - http://application-master-ip:4040 - and see information from Spark Context.

Also, you can check if you can deploy application to Spark Standalone (which you are also starting), just by setting `--master spark://...:` as in configuration. Then you will be sure if it is a problem with YARN or in Spark

BTW. You can omit running Spark Standalone if you're submitting to YARN :) And memory used by Stanalone Workers can be used by YARN

Comment: I try to submit a app use spark-submit with argument --master yarn,

Comment: Sorry... I think enter is newline... The app can be submitted success and get out put like this16/10/12 16:19:33 INFO yarn.Client:
                 client token: N/A
                 diagnostics: N/A
                 ApplicationMaster host: N/A
                 ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
                 queue: default
                 start time: 1476260373944
                 final status: UNDEFINED
                 tracking URL: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1476256306830_0002/
                 user: fuxiuyin

Comment: And I can see the status in yarn web ui, but the app is always in status:ACCEPTED but not RUNNING.

Comment: @fuxiuyin please post your full `spark-submit` command and logs in question, because currently this question suggest that you have mixed Spark Standalone and YARN

Comment: Thanks~, I have edited the problem with submit command and result. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you so much~. My problem is solved and I have added an answer to explain it.

Comment: @fuxiuyin so as I said, there was a problem with resources - but my first thought was RAM, however YARN must allocate all resources, also disk space. Good that it's solved :)

Answer (score 0):

:). Thanks everyone, I'm so sorry to waste your time. When I check the resource in `http://localhost:8088/` I noticed this:

[image: Unhealthy Nodes]

I just stop the server and delete tmp directory and logs directory. Then it works.

Thank you again